# data getting corrupted while writing on to a file - Python

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I'm trying to read data block wise and I've reached till here. I'm able to write data onto a file after I have received it. But some data is not written to the file at regular intervals. Here is the example.

Original File:

```
some text
some text
some text
sends only one message at a time and then waits for a response. If your application might send several messages in a
```

Corrupted File:

```
some text
some text
some text
sends only one message at a time and then waits for a f your application might send several messages in a
```

This is happening at regular intervals after every 6 lines. I'm not able to figure out the problem. Here's the code that I have written.

Receiver Code:

```
while True:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    try:
        s.settimeout(2)
        while(data):
            f.write(data)
            data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    except socket.timeout:
        print("no more data")
```

Can someone guide me what I should change here to receive proper data without breaks as shown.